# Разный cleanup в зависимости от артефактов юнит-теста

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, test-automation

Мой вопрос касается автоматизации тестирования: как можно реализовать проверку TestResult'а после завершения работы тестового метода?

Например, есть код:

```
[TestClass]
public class Class1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Method1()
    {
        MethodA();
        MethodB();
        MethodC();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void AfterTest();
    {
        MethodA();
        MethodB();
    }
}
```

Мне нужно анализировать результат выполнения тестового метода - passed или failed - и, в зависимости от полученного результата, вызывать тот или иной метод тест клинапа.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Используемый фреймворк: UnitTesting.

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201566/how-to-get-test-result-status-from-mstest

Comment: То, что нужно, большое спасибо!